# how to embed a video using URL

Tags: html, video, video-embedding

Quick question:

Is there a general way in which I can embed a video using a URL instead of using 'embed codes' such as `<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/41406753?byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>` or `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/JEPYYo0-gfc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`).

Do I need to manage each case in a separate manner? (extracting ids and constructing a proper iframe tag).

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to use scripting (serverside or clientside) to look for specific urls (Youtube, Vimeo etc.) and generating preset embed codes for them.

Comment: @NADH You were right. I ended up doing something entirely different but if I had done this, I would have needed to manage each case separately. Could you please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Robert : Can you please give me a brief idea how it will start. If it is possible please show me code at client side for submitting url and get embed video(preset video). Please I struggled a lot since one week. I need to implement same as it is as facebook video uploading in my application.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using oEmbed. According to their official website, "oEmbed is a format for allowing an embedded representation of a URL on third party sites. The simple API allows a website to display embedded content (such as photos or videos) when a user posts a link to that resource, without having to parse the resource directly." http://oembed.com/

Answer (score 1):

This code it's going to help you..

```
<iframe  width="425" height="344" 
src="https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/videoplayer/embed/RWfmWf?pid=ocpVideo0-innerdiv-oneplayer&postJsllMsg=true&maskLevel=20&market=es-es" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

you might note src's line... that's the place where you have to write your own URL.

Comment: The question was whether or not the iframe tag can be written in a general manner, or automated somehow.